# Reading an XLS file with codeigniter 2.0

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, spreadsheet

I've got the following problem.

I am trying to read an excel 97 - 2003 (XLS) file.
The file is located within the codeigniter folder.
Currently i am using the 
[spreadsheet_excel_reader.php](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/File%3aSpreadsheet_Excel_Reader.zip/) library to read the XLS file.

Unfortunately i cannot get it working, it does recognize the XLS file and also reads the file, but when it's done parsing the file, it returns `NULL`

This is what my method looks like.

```
$CI =& get_instance();

$this->data_file = "./xls/BolFeed.xls"; //The XLS file and folder

//$CI->spreadsheet_excel_reader->setOutputEncoding('CP1251'); //I've added this one into the library itself.

$CI->spreadsheet_excel_reader->read($this->data_file); //Start reading the XLS file

$this->data_array = $this->spreadsheet_excel_reader->sheets[0]; //This should return my XLS but only returns NULL

var_dump($this->data_array);
die;
```

I think the method does not cause the problem, but the XLS parse library does.

I hope you guys can help me out, because i've been struggling with this problem for days.

I am using PHP 5.3.0 and CI 2.0.0

Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Have you actually loaded the `spreadsheet_excel_reader` library? It doesn't mention this in your code.

Comment: Yes i did, this is actually a library that EXTENDS another library wich i loaded `spreadsheet_excel_reader` in, and using `$CI =& get_instance();` allows me to use it.

Comment: I would suggest looking at phpexcel, I got it working perfectly in CI, only issue is that it gets kind of heavy if you start writing files with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't `$this->spreadsheet_excel_reader->sheets` be `$CI->spreadsheet_excel_reader->sheets`
as you are calling `$CI->spreadsheet_excel_reader->read` in the line above

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is indeed working. I really overlooked that one!

Answer (score 0):

if you do `count($this->spreadsheet_excel_reader->sheets)`  before or after `var_dump` does it show that the array isn't empty?

And from the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/wiki/Documentation), it seems like you need to do more that `sheets` to see data:

```
$this->spreadsheet_excel_reader->dump($row_numbers=false,$col_letters=false,$sheet=0,$table_class='excel');
```