# Codeigniter. extract XLS file to array or similar

Tags: php, codeigniter, import, xls

I'm using CI 2.0.2 and am trying to import a simple XLS file for my site.
Eventually, I'll be inserting that data into a DB, but for now, I just need an array of the data. (I'm going to be running checks on the data first)..

I've never written a plugin for CI and am greatly confused by all the dependancies of these suggestions found in other posts:
[Reading an XLS file with codeigniter 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898001/reading-an-xls-file-with-codeigniter-2-0)
Perhaps this I should be asking 'how to write a plugin'?

Anyhoo, if there's a definative XLS -> array for CI tutorial out there, I can't find it..

I've tried a few methods, but am fearful of over padding my CI directories with 'useless' files.

Feel free to flame me... I'm just tearing out my hair...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading an XLS file with codeigniter 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898001/reading-an-xls-file-with-codeigniter-2-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling XLS files is an utter nightmare...  I've tried lots of libraries (both CI and native PHP) and found nothing that works.

Is saving as a CSV a possibility?

Comment: Sadly not...
I've seen many post by people that have done it in CI but no one has shared their solution that I can find... sadly..